# Use % in javascript / jquery to go backwards in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't really have a problem, I'm just curious if there's a way to refactor a small code. I have a simple slider functionality on a page and to go from current div to the next, I'm using this code:

```
var nextSlideIndex = (allSliderDivs.index(visibleDiv) + 1) % allSliderDivs.length;
```

It iterates through the array in a continous fashion. I also have this code to go backwards:

```
var nextSlideIndex = allSliderDivs.index(visibleDiv) - 1;

if (nextSlideIndex == -1){
    nextSlideIndex = allSliderDivs.length - 1;
}
```

Which works fine as is. I'm just wondering if anyone can think of a way to write the going back code like the going forward code, using `%` or something else, so I don't need to use the `if` code. Following obviously doesn't work `(allSliderDivs.index(visibleDiv) - 1) % allSliderDivs.length`. Any ideas to go back on 1 line?

Comment: Why do you say it obviously doesn't work? I think it should.

Comment: @Barmar Nope. Result of modulo operation can be negative in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
(allSliderDivs.length + allSliderDivs.index(visibleDiv) - 1) % allSliderDivs.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Another less elegant answer is:

```
pos = pos - 1 + length - length * Math.ceil(pos/length);
```

where `pos` is the current position and `length` is the maximum length.